# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop open is marked as required in Snackbar, but its value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, jestjs

I'm trying to introduce `jest` snapshot tests to my app.

**LoginForm** component

```
render() {
    return (
    ...
    <DynamicSnack
        dialogOpen={this.props.dialogOpen}
        snackOpen={this.props.snackOpen}
        snackTimer={this.props.snackTimer}
        snackMessage={this.props.snackMessage}
    />
    )
}
```

**DynamicSnack** component

```
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';

render() {
    let { snackOpen, snackTimer, snackMessage } = this.props

    return (
        <Snackbar
            open={snackOpen}
            message={snackMessage}
            autoHideDuration={snackTimer}
            onRequestClose={this.closeSnack}
        />
    )
}
```

**LoginForm.spec.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import LoginForm from '../../app/components/loginComponents/loginForm'

describe('LoginForm', () => {
    it('should render snapshot', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <LoginForm />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
        const tree = component.toJSON()
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

**Warnings**:

[image]

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `message` is marked as required in `Snackbar`, but its value is `undefined`.
>   Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `Snackbar`, but its value is `undefined`.

I have tried importing the DynamicSnack component and even the Snackbar directly and manually add the properties `open={false} message={'w00f'}`  but nothing changes.

I'm new to unit testing and trying to start by learning `jest`.

**How can i get rid of these warnings?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is very simple, when testing the `LoginForm` you are not passing the props that the `Snackbar` requires. Pass them as

```
 const component = renderer.create(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <LoginForm snackOpen={true}
    snackMessage={'Wrong info'}/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
```

Comment: I swear i tried that at least once before, but maybe something else was different. Now it works :-) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you added, `open` and `message` instead of `snackOpen` and `snackMessage`

Comment: I'm sure i tried both, but maybe it wasn't wrapped in `MuiThemeProvider` at that time. In the future, i will try to use desperate attempts in a less chaotic way :-D

Comment: How do we test that a warning is thrown when no prop is passed?

Answer (score 3):

In a component the required props if we misspelled then we will get this error, In my case I had same problem

**Error:** `<Dialog in={props.open}>`

```
            <Dialog in={props.open}>
                <Alert
                    action={
                        <IconButton
                            aria-label='close'
                            color='inherit'
                            size='small'
                            onClick={useCallback(() => props.closeAlert({ msg: '', open: false }))}
                        >
                            <CloseIcon fontSize='inherit' />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                >
                    {props.msg}
                </Alert>
            </Dialog>
```

Solution: `<Dialog open={props.open}>`

```
        <Dialog open={props.open}>
                <Alert
                    action={
                        <IconButton
                            aria-label='close'
                            color='inherit'
                            size='small'
                            onClick={useCallback(() => props.closeAlert({ msg: '', open: false }))}
                        >
                            <CloseIcon fontSize='inherit' />
                        </IconButton>
                    }
                >
                    {props.msg}
                </Alert>
            </Dialog>
```